# Dataframe comparison in Python gives error "Truth value is ambiguous"

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am running this in Python and I get the following error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
for i in range(meter_reference.shape[0]):
    if (extra['METER_SIZE'] == meter_reference['METER_SIZE'][i] & extra['INSTALL YEAR'] <= meter_reference['Aged Year (normal)'][i]):
        extra['REPLACE'] = 'Replace'
    elif extra['METER_SIZE'] == None:
        extra['REPLACE'] = 'Value Missing'
    else: 
        extra['REPLACE'] = "Do Not Replace"
```

Comment: There are a lot of topics on SO about this. Please search for the error. In short, consider `np.select`.

Comment: I will check that out, thanks

Comment: Look at the individual conditions.  Keep in mind that `if` is a simple onetime switch.  There's no looping.

Comment: Also, use (), e.g. `(x==y)&(x>=3)`, so the tests occur before the combination.  When faced with problems like this, test small pieces of the code.  I like ot keep an interactive python session at hand to test pieces of code.